# How can check what version of Cardano-node is running on testnet or mainnet?

Tags: cardano-node

I recently ran into sync errors after building/installing cardano-node.  I am pretty sure that the problem was that I had built the wrong version, after re-building to exactly what the documentation stated, it synced fine.  So, this begs the question - is there an easy way to find out what version is running on a remote node?

Answer (score 1):

You could check your startup parameters and note the path to the config file you are using by using

```
ps -ef | grep cardano-node
```

There should be a filename after --config

If unchanged, the testnet and mainnet config files are named as such; testnet-config.json and mainnet-config.json.

If the name doesn't suffice, you can check inside this config file which genesis files are used.

Or are you looking for the **latest released** version of cardano-node? This can be done with the following command:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/input-output-hk/cardano-node/releases/latest | jq -r .tag_name
```

[Source: Guild Operators, Build Node/CLI section]

Answer (score 1):

you may connect to the remote node using SSH/RDP.
Then you can run cardano-node or cardano-cli with parameter --version.

```
~$ cardano-node --version
cardano-node 1.30.1 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10

~$ cardano-cli --version
cardano-cli 1.30.1 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
```

Comment: By remote node, I meant the node running on the testnet or mainnet - which I do not own.  So, I don't believe I can ssh into a node I don't own.  I was hoping there either a remote command that I would run that "ask the remote node what version it is running" or it was published somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is ***any*** version (that works!). Anybody is able to pick what they want. What matters is what ***you*** have in this case. If you feel your version is off, just download another one (Releases!), install it and run it!

Comment: True, but I was hoping to avoid a game of "trial and error".

Comment: Welcome to software engineering! haha You could do it backwards. Think about possible errors and constraints to later build around that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is checking a remote node, but are you maybe looking for: `cardano-node --version`?
Example Output:

```
cardano-node 1.27.0 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev 8fe46140a52810b6ca456be01d652ca08fe730bf
```

Or `cardano-cli --version`?
Example Output:

```
cardano-cli 1.27.0 - linux-x86_64 - ghc-8.10
git rev 8fe46140a52810b6ca456be01d652ca08fe730bf
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no (or at least I don't think so).  cardano-node --version will get you what version YOU are running but NOT what version is on the test-net or main-net server(s).  So, I was wondering if the version was posted on some website or if there was a command that could be issued for them to report that info.

Answer (score 0):

Since Cardano is a network of nodes interacting with each other, each node runs its own version, and as long as the versions are compatible, it should be no issue for them to communicate with one another.

If you want to find out the latest version you can run, just head over to the [Release Notes](https://docs.cardano.org/tools/release-notes/) (latest version as of this answer is 8.1.2). Alternatively, you can see their releases on their [github](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/releases).